# How can I fix the issue: "Cannot find module '.todo/todo' or its corresponding type declaration" while specifying relative path to all files?

Tags: nestjs, project-structure

I'm working with the `NestJS` [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/project/tree/main/src/todo) following the next [article](https://medium.com/@niyam-muliya/nestjs-and-its-crud-operations-54b5dd7d6195) (self-learning purposes).

I have the *project-structure* similar to:

```
project
...
src
   |-- app.controller.spec.ts
   |-- app.controller.ts
   |-- app.module.ts
   |-- app.service.ts
   |-- config
   |   |-- database.config.ts
   |-- main.ts
   |-- todo
   |   |-- todo.controller.ts
   |   |-- todo.entity.ts
   |   |-- todo.module.ts
   |   |-- todo.service.ts
```

where I have specifically the folder which contains all `todo` files inside and I need to specify manually *relative* import to this `todo` folder:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Todos } from './todo/todo';

@Module({
  imports: [Todos],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the problem is when I'm trying to do it, I'm getting the issue as:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './todo/todo' or its corresponding type declaration.
```

[image]

Based on it, my *question* is:

how can I specify inside corresponding file `app.module.ts` relative path using *import* to this folder including all files?

I've already checked documentation [Nest Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) and [Nest CLI](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview).
Also I've tried to use commands similar to:

```
npx nest g module/controller/provider
```

which will handle the imports, but I need to find the way how to specify import with relative path including all files.

Can I avoid the usage of any custom `index.ts` files at the route using commands like:

```
export * from './path/to/file/to/export/from
```

just specifying relative path inside import for the file `app.module.ts`?

I appreciate any ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an `index.ts` file at the route where you want the barrel to be, then you use `export * from './path/to/file/to/export/from` as many times as necessary to export all of the things you want to export. Then you can use `import { thing } from '../path/to/<directory>` instead of specifying each file